# Using reduceByKey calculate the positivity by month for New York State

Tags: apache-spark

Using `reduceByKey` calculate the positivity by month for New York State. Then use `Math.round`, `sortBy`, and `collect` to display your results as a percentage with 2 decimal places. A sample of the expected result (the percentage for 10/2022 will change depending on when you pull the data):

```
(2020-03,37.89)
(2020-04,31.79)
(2020-05,5.34)
(2020-06,1.2)
(2020-07,1.08)
(2020-08,0.83)
(2020-09,0.97)
(2020-10,1.3)
(2020-11,2.98)
(2020-12,5.65)
(2021-01,6.27)
(2021-02,3.66)
(2021-03,3.35)
(2021-04,2.69)
(2021-05,1.09)
(2021-06,0.42)
(2021-07,1.56)
(2021-08,3.15)
(2021-09,2.9)
(2021-10,2.31)
(2021-11,3.55)
(2021-12,10.54)
(2022-01,15.09)
(2022-02,2.93)
(2022-03,1.95)
(2022-04,5.45)
(2022-05,7.87)
(2022-06,5.88)
(2022-07,9.54)
(2022-08,7.08)
(2022-09,6.94)
(2022-10,6.71)`
```

Use this info below:

```scala
val counties = Array("Kings","Queens","New+York","Suffolk","Bronx","Nassau","Westchester","Erie",
                     "Monroe","Richmond","Onondaga","Orange","Rockland","Albany","Dutchess",
                     "Saratoga","Oneida","Niagara","Broome","Ulster","Rensselaer","Schenectady",
                     "Chautauqua","Oswego","Jefferson","Ontario","St.+Lawrence","Tompkins",
                     "Putnam","Steuben","Wayne","Chemung","Sullivan","Clinton","Cattaraugus",
                     "Cayuga","Madison","Warren","Columbia","Livingston","Washington","Herkimer",
                     "Otsego","Genesee","Fulton","Montgomery","Greene","Tioga","Franklin","Chenango",
                     "Cortland","Allegany","Delaware","Wyoming","Orleans"
                     ,"Essex","Seneca","Schoharie","Lewis","Yates","Schuyler","Hamilton")

val base_url = "https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/xdss-u53e.json?County="
val urls = counties.map(a => base_url+a) //Makes a url for each county

//This gets the contents of the url
//results is an array with one entry per county
//the data for each county is in JSON format
val results = urls.map(u => scala.io.Source.fromURL(u).mkString) 

//Create an rdd in 32 partitions (there is a lot of data)
//Reads the json and converts it into a spark dataframe (we'll do this later)
//and then converts the df into an rdd
//finally, extract the date, the county name, the new cases on that date and tests done
//on that date
val data_rdd = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(results,32))
                    .rdd
                    .map(r => (r(5).toString.slice(0,10), 
                               r(0).toString,
                               r(4).toString.toInt,
                               r(7).toString.toInt))
```

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: Calculating the positivity % by month with the given info in the val data_rdd